# TryUpdateModel does not update anything for FormView

Tags: asp.net, model, formview

I am using Framework 4.5 and decided to take advantage of some its improvements..
Let's say I have the following control inside FormView:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="EventNumberTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Event_Num %>' />
```

In my UpdateMethod I make the following:

```
public void UpdateModelFromView(int? ID)
{
    var modelView = new AlertMessageController().LoadById(ID);
    var updateSuccess = TryUpdateModel(modelView);
    if (updateSuccess)
    {
        new AlertMessageController().Save(modelView);
        RedirectToViewPage();
    }
}
```

The problem is that although the Form collection does contain all the changes I made - in the given case I have set Event_Num to some value - the changes are not reflected to modelView. In other words, any changes I make into FormView controls, are ignored and the model is saved as is after loading...

Comment: Have you tried using BindItem instead of Item on your TextBox, i.e., BindItem.Event_Num?

Comment: Graham, thank you very much, i feel i am almost there, but now got another problem. The matter is i must take the fields only from the form and ignore URL. When I use TryUpdateModel with one param only - it updates the model with both URL and form parameters. I tried to use second parameter: new NameValueCollectionValueProvider(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form, Culture.GetBrowserOrDefaultCulture()) or new FormValueProvider(Page.ModelBindingExecutionContext), but in these cases TryUpdateModel fully ignores all the changed values...

Comment: I have tried to change parameters for UpdateMethod to accept full object: UpdateModelForView(AlertMessageInfo item). Now ModelState seems to contain all keys from the form, but... its values are not applied, when I try to use TryUpdateModel(modelView, new FormValueProvider(Page.ModelBindingExecutionContext))

Comment: Great you're making progress. Web Forms data binding doesn't take values from the Url (only MVC data binding does that). Web Forms data binding will only take values from the FormView Controls that have BindItem specified. Without seeing more of your code I can't tell what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: It now works, with both using BindItem instead of Item and TryUpdateModel(modelView) - with one parameter. So simple :) But now I am curious, why it did not work when I was using second parameter as new FormValueProvider(Page.ModelBindingExecutionContext)?

Comment: Glad it worked. I've added my comment as an answer if you want to tick it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item is for one-way data binding only. For two-way data binding you should use BindItem, i.e., BindItem.Event_Num.

Comment: Yes, I got it. I just can't figure out, why using TryUpdateModel(modelView, FormValueProvider(Page.ModelBindingExecutionContext)) does not work the same way as TryUpdateModel(modelView). In my opinion, it should work the same...

Comment: And one more question. If I need to use UpdatePanel - how to access Items? Indeed they're getting out of visibility scope in this case!

Comment: The FormValueProvider isn't used by Web Forms when it data binds. The FormValueProvider is for MVC where the names of the inputs match the names of the model properties.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Then I have one more question :) In some situations I need to change the values in Update method before actual db updating. But when I try to use sequence: Page.ModelBindingExecutionContext.ModelState.Remove("Alert_Id");
    Page.ModelBindingExecutionContext.ModelState.SetModelValue("Alert_Id", ....); - the model DOES update those params. However, TryUpdateModel(modelView) fully ignores these new values... Do I need to always update source item parameter in Update method instead?

Comment: Damn... It did not help :( I have modified the parameters of the ITEM that came as parameter in Update method, but these values have not been applied to the modelView by TryUpdateModel method...

Comment: Update the values directly on the model after calling TryUpdateModel, i.e., TryUpdateModel(modelView); modelView.Name = "changed name";

Comment: Aha, yes... Or, which was a preferable in my case, I've made all conditional assignment logic in SelectMethod to have BindItem correct from the start. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Anik, I believe that the form field name needs to match the property name.

Comment: I have tried this, of course. No luck :( I also have tried to use another version of TryUpdateModel method:    TryUpdateModel(modelView, new NameValueCollectionValueProvider(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form, Culture.GetBrowserOrDefaultCulture())) - no luck also.

Comment: But wait a min: do you mean NAMES? So, I need to add a name to each form control in addition to ID? I cannot try this in the moment, but I'm curious..

Comment: When ASP.NET generates Html for the TextBox, it automatically creates a name for it based on the ID. That name needs to match the Property name. If you use the HtmlHelpers to generate your form and input fields, it handles this for you.

Comment: Yeap, the name is assigned and it's the same as ID. The problem is that even if ClientIdMode is set to static - overall the ID looks like this: "ctl00$cphMain$ctl00$ctl00$FormView$Event_Num" instead of simple "Event_Num" as I indicate. It's an usual ASP.NET markup - we do not use MVC and Razor or other stuff like this in current project, so no any HtmlHelpers. SO... have no idea what else can be tried out.

Comment: They did add ModelBinding to WebForms in 4.5, but I haven't used it. According to MSDN:

This method should only be called from a method that is specified by a data-bound control's UpdateMethod or InsertMethod property.

For a tutorial series on using model binding with Web Forms, see [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=286117).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, their example is quite narrow. I have downloaded it to analyze. They do not demonstrate FormView update methods, only grids, so I have no idea about IDs and NAMEs of FormView controls. I thought that bound values should be enough to set correspondence to actual properties for update (i.e. Item.Event_Num). There is one more weird thing: when I click on TryUpdateModel method - it takes me to UserControl, but it does not show this method's description! But I do have FrameWork 4.5 installed and my documentation is taken from ONLINE source...